# How to set a gradient background to a Material Button?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, material-components-android

I'm currently using this code but the background is not changing.It is still showing accent-color as background.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/materialButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    app:cornerRadius="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradiant_blue"/>
```

gradiant_blue.xml

```
<shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

   <gradient
       android:angle="-45"
       android:startColor="#2979FF"
       android:endColor="#7C4DFF"/>
</shape>
```

I'm currently using

> Material Components version : 1.0.0-rc02

Comment: What is `gradiant_blue`? You should post its code

Comment: @Pavan you can go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908045/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-in-a-material-button-from-material-components?rq=1). Hope this helps you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To use a custom drawable background with the `MaterialButton` you can use the `android:background` attribute:

```
<MaterialButton
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_button_gradient"
    ... />
```

**NOTE:** It **requires** at least the version **[`1.2.0-alpha06`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/309d71860f0686137277915fb09e7502cbafc2b4)**

Currently it is very important to add **`app:backgroundTint="@null"`** to avoid that the custom background doesn't get tinted by default with  the `backgroundTint` color.

With lower versions of the Material Components Library you have to use an **`AppCompatButton`**.

Comment: Brother this is work.. But it make no corner radius..

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the tint.

Answer (score 9):

**LE:** From my point of view I suggest you use `Button` or `AppCompatButton`.

Try this:

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#027FEE"
        android:startColor="#2CC6F2" />
</shape>
```

**button.xml**

```
<!-- replace MaterialButton with Button or AppCompatButton -->
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/materialButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:text="Hello" />
```

Result:

[image: result]

With `corner radius` change **gradient.xml** to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#027FEE"
        android:startColor="#2CC6F2" />
    <corners android:radius="32dp"/>
</shape>
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: which version are you using. I tried your code but still not working

Comment: The background isn't changing?

Comment: can you once try with - " 'implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02' "

Comment: there is no error and the background is not changing. It is not even changing in preview mode and also not changing in actual device

Comment: same gradient is working fine with other views and buttons

Comment: The other buttons are `Button` type? Why do you use `MaterialButton` for this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180226/discussion-between-pavan-varma-and-grrigore).

Comment: For material btn don`t foget add ```app:backgroundTint="@null"```

Answer (score -1):

Please read the documentation for Material button,  from [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

It says, 
"For filled buttons, your theme’s colorPrimary provides the default background color of the component, and the text color is colorOnPrimary. For unfilled buttons, your theme’s colorPrimaryprovides the default text color of the component, and the background color is transparent by default."

I think that's the reason you are seeing some other color(accent-color) also please check the attributes that set background colour.

Following attributes are mentioned :

`app:backgroundTint`

`app:backgroundTintMode`

Comment: I need to put gradient background. background-tint does not allow drawables.

Answer (score -5):

To set background you need to make your base theme extend

> Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

and not

> Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: If your theme does not extend from MaterialComponents, you can not use Material Button

Comment: `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` is only available for materialComponents theme not appcompat themes