# How to set a gradient background in a Material Button from Material Components?

Tags: android, gradient, android-button, material-components-android

I've been trying to set a gradient background in a Material Button from Material Components for Android, but it's not working.
So, how to set a gradient background in a Material Button?

Comment: That isn't possible to easily change background color to a gradient currently. The only way you could achieve that is by creating your own gradient drawable and setting that to the material button.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [the documentation for `MaterialButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton):

> Do not use the `android:background` attribute. MaterialButton manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means `MaterialButton` can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, `MaterialButton` cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

The only supported way to modify the background of the button is to set a color value to the `app:backgroundTint` attribute. Unfortunately, gradients are not supported here either; you can only use a simple color value or a `ColorStateList`.

So, there is no supported way to use a gradient background with MaterialButton.

Answer (score 26):

Starting with the version [**`1.2.0-alpha06`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/309d71860f0686137277915fb09e7502cbafc2b4) you can use the **`android:background`** attribute in the `MaterialButton`.

```
<MaterialButton
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    ... />
```

Otherwise if you can't use the 1.2.0-alpha06 or higher you have to use the **`AppCompatButton`** component.

Just a some tips about the **`MaterialButton`**.

- Currently the `backgroundTint` is still the default MaterialButton style.
  If you are using a custom `android:background`, you **have to make sure to null out** `backgroundTint` (either `app:backgroundTint="@null"` or `app:backgroundTint="@empty"`), to avoid that the custom background doesn't get tinted.
- using a custom `android:background` the default `MaterialShapeDrawable` is not used. Some features like stroke, shapeappearance, ripple are not set (since they are related to the `MaterialShapeDrawable`) . You have to provide them with your custom background.

Comment: had to come back to see the backgroundTint tip. This is key! I put a gradient on my button and it had the wrong colors. Thanks for that pointer.

Comment: I lost ripple color effect on a button on which I used this method. Do you know how to save ripple effect?

Comment: @StayCool Using a custom background you are removing the ShapeMaterialDrawable which handles also the ripple. You have to apply a custom RippleDrawable to your background.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I changed my drawable_background.xml that contained only shape, to <ripple> xml, that contained either shape and ripple items :) Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Make use of `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` if you are using Material Theme to be able to apply background gradients, because Material Button doesn't offer support to it yet.

For background gradient, create 3 new resources in `drawable` folder:

**selector_btn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- disabled state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_gradient_inactive" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_gradient_active" />
</selector>
```

**btn_gradient_inactive.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#01579B"
        android:endColor="#1A237E"
        android:angle="0" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/> </shape>
```

**btn_gradient_active.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#2196F3"
        android:endColor="#3F51B5"
        android:angle="0" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

In your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="BtnStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_btn_gradient</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

In your `layout.xml` file:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/my_btn_id"
    style="@style/BtnStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/selector_gradient_example"
      app:backgroundTint="@null" />
```

**selector_gradient_example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/banana_yellow">
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <ripple android:color="@color/banana_yellow">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient android:angle="135" android:endColor="@color/banana_yellow" android:startColor="@color/main_yellow" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="315" android:endColor="#ede0be" android:startColor="#e0bf7e" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Answers should not be simple snippets of code. Can you elaborate on why and how this code answers the question?

Comment: This solution works since `app:backgroundTint` has no effect even if set with drawable. Setting the background to drawable gradient and app background tint, makes the gradient work on the button

Answer (score 0):

Removing backgroundTint attribute in xml worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

**btn_gradient.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#469FED"
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#2AC88D"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

**and use this instead of a button:**

```
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="40dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="send" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```