# How to set a Gradient Background Color to a Card (from Material Components)

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components

I was wondering if there is any way to set a **gradient background color** to a Card from the Material Components. I was reading through the [docs,](https://material.io/develop/android/components/cards) but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908045/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-in-a-material-button-from-material-components?rq=1)?

Comment: It's different though once a `Card` is a ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml below res/drawable and set the background of your cardview to this xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
        <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorPurple"
                android:endColor="@color/colorBlue"
                android:angle="0"/>
    
    </shape>
```