# Corner radius property missing on MaterialButton after update to Material 1.2.0

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, materialbutton

Here's my MaterialButton code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="224dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:text="@string/onboarding_next_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cornerRadius="25dp" />
```

After update Material library from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 the app:CornerRadius is ignored. I try with shape theme follow the Material documentation but the control still totally square

Comment: I found it working fine in 1.2.0. Try Invalidate cache and restart android studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:background`

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
   .../>
```

Starting with [`1.2.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908045/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-in-a-material-button-from-material-components/61610556#61610556) it is possible to use the `android:background` in the `MaterialButton`. **Using a custom android:background the default `MaterialShapeDrawable` is not used** and some features like stroke, shapeappearance, corners radius, ripple are not set (since they are related to the `MaterialShapeDrawable`) and you have to provide them with your custom background

Since you are using a simple color as background just use `app:backgroundTint`.

[image]