# Button Doesn't Show Correct Color - Android Studio

Tags: android, button, android-button, material-components-android, materialbutton

In my Android Studio application, I have a button for which I set a drawable as the background. The drawable rounds the corners and changes the color of the button.
However, when I look at the resulting design of the activity, the color I want doesn't show up. Instead, the button assumes colorPrimary (orange, #ED3616). The same occurs when I run the application.
Note: the other attributes of the drawable file translate perfectly to the button (i.e. the rounded corners). The problem is only with the color.

I have tried using a MaterialButton, and setting the color with android:backgroundTint. Then, the color does show up as I want to, but the design looks odd (there is a different colored rectangle inside of the button([Picture of MaterialButton if you'd like to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHJAb.png))

How can I make the regular button have the color I desire?

Button:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/round2"
    android:id="@+id/signIn"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:text="@string/logIn"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.878" />
```

Drawable: round2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#B30C44"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="6dp"
        android:left="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:top="6dp" />
</shape>
```

What shows up:
[What the Button looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skPQP.png)

Comment: I tried your code and it gives me a button with the color you want (like the first image) but without the colored rectangle inside. You want the rectangle inside?

Comment: @KKKKK, I would like it without the rectangle inside. The reason why I'm so confused is because this problem doesn't occur in any of my other projects; it only occurs in this android project. Thank you for trying anyways!

Comment: if you want to change the color of your button you have to change the color inside the round2.xml file, idk your code on my android studio and device works very well :(

Comment: try to set your color on colors.xml file and call it where it needs

Comment: I just set the color on the colors.xml file, and called it in my round2.xml file. But, the problem remains

Comment: Try build -> clean project, or uninstall and install your apk

Comment: Or try Tools>Android>Theme Editor and change the primary color

Comment: I finished the ideas :)

Comment: @KKKKK How do I uninstall and reinstall my apk?

Comment: If you use an emulator when you run the code you dont Need that, instead if you use your device (like Samsung, Xiaomi..) then delete the apk and run again the code

Comment: I used an emulator, so I don't think that's the problem. The other ideas didn't work either. Thank you so much for trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because the default style of the `MaterialButton` (the `Button` is replaced with a `MaterialButton` automatically if your are using a `MaterialComponents` theme) [tints the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908045/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-in-a-material-button-from-material-components/61610556#61610556) with the `colorPrimary`.

You have to use:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/round2"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    ... />
```