# stroke attribute isn't working for a button in android studio

Tags: android, button, android-button, android-styles, material-components-android

**Here is my Buttons.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <gradient android:startColor="#8E8816"
        android:endColor="#145038"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke android:color="#680D0D" android:width="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

**and here is my activity_main.xml**
**i tried to change the android:background as android:src but then also it's not working**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/teal_700"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Only the corners attribute is working fine**

**not only the stroke but also the background is not changing
i'm not getting where i'm doing wrong...can anyone help me**

**here how to button looks like after applying the background as android:background="@drawable/buttons"**
[Button_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfg0o.png)

Comment: This should work unless the colors are not mixing up with root background `teal_700` ..can u add a screen shot

Comment: I don't see any problem in there. Maybe clean and rebuild project.

Comment: added the screen shot

Comment: I tried to do the same thing  for many project ..the result are same.

Comment: Post your app theme. Are you using the material Components library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because the `Button` is replaced with a `MaterialButton` automatically if your are using a `MaterialComponents` theme and the default style of the `MaterialButton` [tints the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908045/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-in-a-material-button-from-material-components/61610556#61610556) with the `colorPrimary`.

You have to use:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    ... />
```

[image]