# Set background color and border color of Button using Shape Drawable in Android 8

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, android-button

I am trying to set background color and border color of Button using Shape Drawable (create button_start.xml in drawable) in Android 8, but it does not seem to work.

**button_start.xml file:**
[image]

**activity_main.xml file:**
[image]

**result:**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**.
You don't need to define a background shape, just use a `MaterialButton` with the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/...."
            app:strokeColor="@color/...."
            app:strokeWidth="5dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:text="BUTTON"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle"
            />
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

---

**Long answer:**
If you want to use a background shape you have to add `app:backgroundTint="@null"`.
Something like:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

Using a Material Components Theme the `Button` is replaced at runtime by a `MaterialButton` which use a own `MaterialShapeDrawable` as background.
You can define a custom background but to avoid that the custom background doesn't get tinted you have to add `app:backgroundTint="@null"`.
**The 2 solutions are not equivalent.**
Using a custom `android:background` the default `MaterialShapeDrawable` is not used and some features like stroke, shapeappearance, ripple are not set (since they are related to the `MaterialShapeDrawable`) . You have to provide them with your custom background.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, sir. However, can you explain why my method does not work ? I want to know the reason for deeply understanding.

Comment: @ManhHai Using a Material Components Theme (I suppose you are using it) the `Button` is replaced at runtime with a `MaterialButton` which uses an own background. You can define a custom background (but it is not the best option) but to avoid that the custom background doesn't get tinted you have to add `app:backgroundTint="@null"`. With the solution proposed your using all the default features.More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610556/2016562)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `solid` property in your shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#4E008E" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```