# How to add a gradient background to a Material Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to add a gradient background to a Material Button, using this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        />

</shape>
```

I'm trying it setting up the background like:

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

But it just doesn't work. I know to setup a solid color I can do it like:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/solid"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Add Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371234/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-to-a-material-button) OR [How to set..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908045/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-in-a-material-button-from-material-components)

Comment: can you share your button's XML?

Comment: At the end I will just not user MaterialButton, doesn't seem to support gradients as background